# XMLport Table Attributes

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

XMLport objects in NAV appear to support table attributes (i.e. Node Type = Attribute, Source Type = Table). However, when I try to save an XMLport containing a table attribute node in NAV 2013, I get this error message:

```
The SourceType Table for Tag <MyTableAttribute> can only be assigned to TagType Element.
```

This (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh165612(v=nav.70).aspx) page on MSDN seems to confirm that table attributes can be used. What purpose would a table attribute serve? What would be an example of a typical application of table attributes?

Comment: And what result you trying to achieve by setting this? What result XML should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table (record) cannot be source for attribute. Because record is a set of fields, i.e. it has multiple values, when attribute must have concrete single value. A field can be used as source for attribute of element. And record must be source for the element. That is what error message says.

Comment: That's what I thought, Mak Sim - what you're saying makes sense. Still, the page on MSDN appears to contains a section dedicated to table attributes? Do you think the documentation there is wrong?

Comment: The only explanation I have for this is that Table Attribute has properties indeed (one can see it by pressing Shift+F4)...but! The other thing is such combination of parameters is forbidden for usage. I suppose MSDN page was automatically generated. If you look inside of ReqFilterHeadingML Property for example, you'll see that it is `Applies To: Table **elements** on XMLports` not to table attributes.